# How was the number of 32 endorsements arrived at?

Tags: endorser

I'm wondering if there is a special reason that 32 endorsements for a block was chosen vs any other number?

It seems very close to 33.333 which would ring a BFT bell, but not quite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a compromise between convergence speed for consensus and not having too large of an overhead per block. Why 32 specifically? It has to be some number, and 32 is a nice round number.